# I want to be able to use check boxes to allow users to select which parameters they want to add into their password in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, actionevent

```
//Removed imports as I felt they were uneccessary to include
//So my program currently can produce a string of 16 characters with random chars from the strings 
//(cont.) LOWER, UPPER, NUMBERS, SYMBOLS
//I want to be able to check specific boxes that will allow me to "filter" what chars i select
```

```
public class Main implements ActionListener{
    
    public final static String LOWER = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    public final static String UPPER = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    public final static String NUMBERS = "0123456789";
    public final static String SYMBOLS = "~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\\:;\"'<,>.?/";
    static JButton genButton;
    static JTextField textGenPassword;
    static generatePassword password;
    static JCheckBox upperCheckBox;
    static JCheckBox lowerCheckBox;
    static JCheckBox numCheckBox;
    static JCheckBox symbolCheckBox;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        password = new generatePassword();
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();   
        JPanel configPanel = new JPanel(); 
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel title = new JLabel();
        JLabel configTitle = new JLabel();
        JCheckBox upperCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
        JCheckBox lowerCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
        JCheckBox numCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
        JCheckBox symbolCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
        JLabel configUpperLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel configLowerLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel configNumLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel configSymbolLabel = new JLabel();
        textGenPassword = new JTextField();
        genButton = new JButton("Generate Password");
        
        //Title panel
        titlePanel.setBackground(new Color(25, 25, 25));
        titlePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        titlePanel.add(title);
        titlePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        
        title.setText("Strong Password Generator");
        title.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        title.setFont(new Font("Roboto", Font.BOLD, 20));
        
        //Config Panel
        configPanel.add(configTitle);
        configPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(9,1,20,10));
        configTitle.setText("Configuration Settings");
        configTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        configTitle.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER);
        configTitle.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        Border configBorder = new EmptyBorder(20, 0, 0, 0);
        configTitle.setBorder(configBorder);
        
        
        //upercase group
        configPanel.add(configUpperLabel);
        configUpperLabel.setText("Uppercase Letters");
        configUpperLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        configPanel.add(upperCheckBox);
        upperCheckBox.addActionListener(password);
        upperCheckBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        upperCheckBox.setBackground(new Color(107, 208, 255));
        

        //lowercase group
        configPanel.add(configLowerLabel);
        configLowerLabel.setText("Lowercase Letters");
        configLowerLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        configPanel.add(lowerCheckBox);
        lowerCheckBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lowerCheckBox.setBackground(new Color(107, 208, 255));
        
        //num group
        configPanel.add(configNumLabel);
        configNumLabel.setText("Numbers: ( e.g. 123)");
        configNumLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        configPanel.add(numCheckBox);
        numCheckBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        numCheckBox.setBackground(new Color(107, 208, 255));
        
        //symbol group
        configPanel.add(configSymbolLabel);
        configSymbolLabel.setText("Symbols: ( e.g. ! @ $)");
        configSymbolLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        configPanel.add(symbolCheckBox);
        symbolCheckBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        symbolCheckBox.setBackground(new Color(107, 208, 255));

        
        configPanel.setBackground(new Color(107, 208, 255));
        configPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,150));
    

        //Main panel
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        mainPanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 150));

        textGenPassword.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 25));
        textGenPassword.setLocation(100, 100);
        textGenPassword.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        
        genButton.addActionListener(password);

        //gridbag constraints
        GridBagConstraints textFieldConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        textFieldConstraints.gridx = 0; 
        textFieldConstraints.gridy = 0; 
        textFieldConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        textFieldConstraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5); 

        
        mainPanel.add(textGenPassword, textFieldConstraints);

        
        GridBagConstraints buttonConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        buttonConstraints.gridx = 0; 
        buttonConstraints.gridy = 1; 
        buttonConstraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5); 

        
        mainPanel.add(genButton, buttonConstraints);
        
        frame.setSize(900,600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setResizable(false);
        
        frame.add(titlePanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(configPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(mainPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == genButton) {
            textGenPassword.setText(password.genPassword());
        }
        
    }



}

//start of separate class in separate file

public class generatePassword extends Main implements ActionListener{
    

    public String genPassword() {
        
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        String combinedChars = LOWER + UPPER + NUMBERS + SYMBOLS;
        StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder(16);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            int num = random.nextInt(combinedChars.length());
            password.append(combinedChars.charAt(num));
        }
        
        return password.toString();
        
    }
    
    
}
```

I have tried to set up actioneventlisteners and itemeventlisteners on the check boes, but im not sure what im doing wrong?

I'll write something like this

```
@Override

        if(upperCheckBox.isSelected()) {
            combinedChars += UPPER;
        }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == genButton) {
            textGenPassword.setText(password.genPassword());
        }
        
    }
```

I will set the combinedChars variable to null before doing this, as well as trying to add the event listener to the checkbox, but nothing i seem to do works? I am really lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rearranged your code to create the following GUI:

[image: SPG]

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

The first thing I did was to separate the creation of the `JFrame` and the `JPanels` into separate methods.  This makes the code much easier for other people to read, separates your concerns, and allows you to focus on one part of the Swing GUI at a time.

Next, I reordered the code so it's executed in the correct order.  The `JFrame` methods **must be called in a specific order**.  The order I coded is the order I use for most of my Swing applications.  `JPanels` should be created in column, row order.

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

The only fields that need to be class instance fields are the fields that you use in more than one method.  Defining all your fields as class fields is a bad habit that confuses readers of your code.

None of your fields need to be static.

The `ActionListener` is attached to your `JButton`.  I build the `combinedChars` `String` based on your checkboxes, check to make sure at least one check box is checked, and create the password.  You might want to consider adding a `JSlider` to your GUI somewhere to specify the length of the password.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class PasswordGenerator implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PasswordGenerator());
    }

    private JCheckBox upperCheckBox, lowerCheckBox, numCheckBox, symbolCheckBox;

    private JTextField textGenPassword;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Strong Password Generator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createTitlePanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(createConfigurationPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createTitlePanel() {
        JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        titlePanel.setBackground(new Color(25, 25, 25));
        titlePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 60));

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Strong Password Generator");
        title.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        title.setFont(new Font("Roboto", Font.BOLD, 20));
        titlePanel.add(title);

        return titlePanel;
    }

    private JPanel createConfigurationPanel() {
        JPanel configPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 20, 10));

        JLabel configTitle = new JLabel("  Configuration Settings  ");
        configTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        configTitle.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER);
        configTitle.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        configTitle.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 0, 0, 0));
        configPanel.add(configTitle);

        Color backgroundColor = new Color(107, 208, 255);

        // uppercase group
        JLabel configUpperLabel = new JLabel();
        configUpperLabel.setText("Uppercase Letters");
        configUpperLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        configPanel.add(configUpperLabel);

        upperCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
        upperCheckBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        upperCheckBox.setBackground(backgroundColor);
        configPanel.add(upperCheckBox);

        // lowercase group
        JLabel configLowerLabel = new JLabel("Lowercase Letters");
        configLowerLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        configPanel.add(configLowerLabel);

        lowerCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
        lowerCheckBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lowerCheckBox.setBackground(backgroundColor);
        configPanel.add(lowerCheckBox);

        // num group
        JLabel configNumLabel = new JLabel("Numbers: ( e.g. 123)");
        configNumLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        configPanel.add(configNumLabel);

        numCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
        numCheckBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        numCheckBox.setBackground(backgroundColor);
        configPanel.add(numCheckBox);

        // symbol group
        JLabel configSymbolLabel = new JLabel("Symbols: ( e.g. ! @ $)");
        configSymbolLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        configPanel.add(configSymbolLabel);

        symbolCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
        symbolCheckBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        symbolCheckBox.setBackground(backgroundColor);
        configPanel.add(symbolCheckBox);

        return configPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        mainPanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));

        GridBagConstraints textFieldConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        textFieldConstraints.gridx = 0;
        textFieldConstraints.gridy = 0;
        textFieldConstraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        textGenPassword = new JTextField(20);
        mainPanel.add(textGenPassword, textFieldConstraints);

        GridBagConstraints buttonConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        buttonConstraints.gridx = 0;
        buttonConstraints.gridy = 1;
        buttonConstraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        JButton genButton = new JButton("Generate Password");
        genButton.addActionListener(this);
        mainPanel.add(genButton, buttonConstraints);

        return mainPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String numbers = "0123456789";
        String symbols = "~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\\:;\"'<,>.?/";
        String combinedChars = "";

        if (upperCheckBox.isSelected()) {
            combinedChars += upper;
        }

        if (lowerCheckBox.isSelected()) {
            combinedChars += lower;
        }

        if (numCheckBox.isSelected()) {
            combinedChars += numbers;
        }

        if (symbolCheckBox.isSelected()) {
            combinedChars += symbols;
        }

        if (combinedChars.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder(16);

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            int num = random.nextInt(combinedChars.length());
            password.append(combinedChars.charAt(num));
        }

        textGenPassword.setText(password.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: im confused why you have to return the panel. isnt the instance just created already? or does that make it available to the rest of the code program

Comment: @bpatrick24: Returning the `JPanel` from a method makes it available to be placed on the `JFrame`.  Any field you define in a method stays in the method unless it's returned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your genButton's action listener.

```
genButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            genButtonActionPerformed(evt);
     }
});
```

And then make your button listener active

```
private void genButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      ....
}
```